# Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body sort method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jslint

I am getting the following error **Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body** when I run this code.

```
getters: {
loadedMeetups(state) {
  return state.loadedMeetups.sort((meetupA, meetupB) => {
    return meetupA.date > meetupB.date;
  });
},
```

I can't figure out why it would be giving me this error.

Comment: That's just a linting problem; given the trivial content of the function, it's expecting `.sort((meetupA, meetupB) => meetupA.date > meetupB.date)`.

Answer (score 0):

If a fat arrow function just consists of a `return` statement, you don't need to wrap it in braces, just put the expression being returned:

```
getters: {
    loadedMeetups(state) {
        return state.loadedMeetups.sort((meetupA, meetupB) => meetupA.date > meetupB.date);
},
```

JSLint is simply warning that you have this redundant code.